# Line Chart x points values auto resize form a dictionary of key values

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, charts

I have a problem where I 'm supplying a collection of key value pairs (x,y values to a chart to display).

For ex:

```
           Dictionary<int, double> values = new Dictionary<int, double>
                    {
                        {1, 12},
                        {2, 25},
                        {3, 77},
                        {4, 12},
                        {5, 25},
                        {6, 77},
                        {7, 12},
                        {8, 25},
                        {9, 77},
                        {10, 12}
                    };
```

Now the chart displays ok with around 30 values but when the values is more than 100 it gets clunked.

What's the best way to auto re-size the dictionary let's say to a given count (30) out of any infinite future values let's say 200.

So I would have a function AutoSizeDictioanry(values, 30); //30 is the desired limit
so it would return a dictionary of values that would look like:

```
public Dictionary<int, double> AutoSizeDictioanry(Dictionary<int, double> dict, int limit)
{
    // logic for resizing the dictionary        
   Dictionary<int, double> resized = new Dictionary<int, double>
                            {
                                {3, 45}, // this would be for example first 3 values with their average
                                {8, 33}, // this would be the following 5 values with their average 
                                {5, 22}, //etc
                            };
    return resized ;
}
```

Not sure if I'm even approaching this correctly but what I am trying to achieve is to show a line chart nicely from a big amount of values.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try to feed your charting function with your dictionary, filtered (using LINQ Extensions) with a `Top(30)`.

Comment: What you are suggesting seems like a very random way to sample the data and I think the results will not be a very good representation of the data. If I were you I would either find better charting library that is capable of displaying more data points (100 is not very many) what are you using at the moment? Also check this out: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/982 It might be a good place to get started looking for the best way to sample your data to reduce the number of points.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm using highcharts javascript library to display the chart. It connects to the back end to get the json data to display. The issue I am having is that its works ok when getting like 100 items but when I am getting 10000 items the the chart needs to display a lot of data and it might not handle it so well. I found a way to sample it on the back end and will post the solution soon.

Comment: *soon* -- on which timescale?